# JavaScript document.write(encoded html tag), print as it is

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml

I am using javascript to generate HTML page from XML (generate table from XML file),
well I have some kind of XML structure etc. I write HTML code as follows

```
document.write("<span>" + name + "</span>");
```

I get my variable as follows

```
name = x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

So variable **name** contains whatever node **NAME** in my XML file structure contains
simple XML to demonstrate:

```
<FILE>
<NAME>file 1.2.3</NAME>
<SIZE>1Kb</SIZE>
</FILE>
```

The XML file is beeing edited by user, so user may insert whatever he/she wants, so if user inputs: `<script>alert(1);</script>` in to NAME node JavaScript is going to print out regular HTML and browser is going to call "alert(1)". Thats what I do not want to happen.

All editing is done with "my" front-end, and thru php function htmlspecialchars(); so actually what user would save into NAME node is "encoded" HTML

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(3);&lt;/script&gt;
```

even all that it is not enough, when XML is saved with encoded HTML tags, javascript prints them as normal tags.

In other words: How can I write on page using JS (document.write) following text: **`<?php $=1; ?>`** or **`<htmltag>whatever is here </htmltag>`** without corrupting my real HTML.

Any solution?

example, this does not work as I would expect:

```
document.write("<span class=\"edit\">&lt;script&gt;alert(3);&lt;/script&gt;</span>");
```

**SOLUTION**

Found this function on web

```
function htmlspecialchars(str) {
 if (typeof(str) == "string") {
  str = str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;"); /* must do &amp; first */
  str = str.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
  str = str.replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
  str = str.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
  str = str.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
 }
return str;
}
```

It does the job done, but I do not really understand why.

In XML file it is already "encoded" or in form that should be safe to render (send to document.write function). I simply do "htmlspecialchars" again and it works pretty well.

```
document.write("<span>" + htmlspecialchars(name) + "</span>");
```

Comment: You can not print XML verbatim in HTML without properly encoding it. `<` for example is a special character in HTML. See SGML, HTML: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1866#section-3.1

Comment: Depending on what you aim for, you need to take care of CDATA sections, because HTML does not have those, but XML has them. Also if you found something on the web, leave a link where you got it from. Also add your solution as an answer, not by editing the question. Accept it then. This is how this website works.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use "single quote"? :

```
document.write('<span class="edit">' + name + '</span>');
```

If you want to create dynamic elements and if you want to use those elements with javascript again, you should use DOM functions (createElement, createTextNode, createAttribute):

http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/createElement

Comment: I just generate table with javascript, problem is when **name** contains encoded html tag(s) it is printed out as "normal" tags. It has nothing to do with single quote (I am 99% sure).